# c++ template problem

Tags: c++, class, templates

i have a class which has a template by other purposes:

```
template<class t>
class MyClass {
    public: //of course public...
    t foo;
    std::string text;
}
```

and i have another class which method get all kind of these class through the arguments, and want to store the pointer in an array. The class dont want to access the specific (tempalted) parts of the classes only the common attributes/methods.

```
class Container {
    public: //of course public...
    MyClass* array; //this is allocated with some magic.
    void bar(MyClass& m) {
      and want to store the class in a MyClass* array.
    }
}
```

here is the error that **argument list for template missing**

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method would be to make that function a template as well:

```
template <class t>
void bar(MyClass<t>& m) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that that should probably be `const MyClass<t>&`, because you don't need to modify it.

---

Your new code is meaningless. There is no such that as an object of type `MyClass`, because `MyClass` is a *template*. If you want to operate on these classes irrespective of their template argument, then you need to factor out the non-template portions as a base class:

```
class MyClassBase
{
public:
    // polymorphic base classes should always have virtual destructors
    ~MyClassBase() {}

    virtual void some_function() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass : public MyClassBase
{
public:
    // implement abstract functions
    void some_function()
    {
        // template argument T is available here
    }
};
```

Then you can refer to that base, and when you call a virtual function it will dynamically dispatch:

```
class Container
{
public:
    // no magic: use a std::vector for dynamic arrays
    std::vector<MyClassBase*> array; // not by value! avoid slicing

    void bar(MyClassBase& m)
    {
        array.push_back(&m);
    }

    void baz()
    {
        array[0]->some_function(); // for example
    }
};
```

Comment: As the compiler tells you, you **must** pass a template argument to `MyClass`.

Comment: sorry this is not really correct because another class method need to access the MyClass attribute, and this is my Mistake that i dont said that. i will update my q in a second

Answer (score 3):

How about putting a common base class.

```
class MyClassCommon {
protected:
    ~MyClassCommon() { }

public:
    std::string text;
};

template<class t>
class MyClass : public MyClassCommon {
public: // of course public...
    t foo;
};

class Container {
public: // of course public...
    MyClassCommon* array; // this is allocated with some magic.
    void bar(MyClassCommon& m) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't see you added this, didn't mean to step on your toes.

Comment: thanks for your answer as well. i upvoted you for this nice answer, but i understand more GMan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a "multi-template" array, you'd better use a non-template class as a base class of a template class. Or you can make a template array and store any objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

the text variable in your class is private so unless you bar function is a method of the class you can't legally use it like that

Comment: Good observation, but I think we can assume that's a typo. :)