# How to Make a vector of template structs

Tags: c++, templates, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ template problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614412/c-template-problem)

Hi Everyone:

I'm stuck trying to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
  struct test {
  T* value;
  test(int num_of_elements) { value = new T[num_of_elements] };
  }

  std::vector<test *> fields_;
```

i.e. I want to make a vector of pointers to a set of test structs with different types for value?

How do I do this?

Thanks

Ross

Comment: That's nonsensical: It's a *template*, not an object. There's nothing to point at.

Comment: Arguable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614412/c-template-problem/

Comment: Yes but I crate objects of test and put those into the vector fields. I just need each instance of test to have different types for value.

Comment: @user: Again, that doesn't make conceptual sense, there's no such thing as a `test` or `test*`. Take a look at the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any.html).  An example from the documentation illustrates your use case almost exactly (at least, as you've described so far):

```
struct property
{
    property();
    property(const std::string &, const boost::any &);

    std::string name;
    boost::any value;
};

typedef std::list<property> properties;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it means to make a pointer to a test template (contrast with test class). But, if you are sure you want that, you could try:

```
  struct baseTest {
    virtual GetNumberOfElems() = 0;
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct test : public baseTest {
    std::size_t n;
    T* value;
    test(int num_of_elements) { value = new T[n = num_of_elements] };
    int GetNumberOfElems() { return n; } 
  }

  std::vector<baseTest *> fields_;
```