# C++ One std::vector containing template class of multiple types

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector

I need to store multiple types of a template class in a single vector.

Eg, for:

```
template <typename T>
class templateClass{
     bool someFunction();
};
```

I need one vector that will store all of:

```
templateClass<int> t1;
templateClass<char> t2;
templateClass<std::string> t3;
etc
```

As far as I know this is not possible, if it is could someone say how?

If it isn't  possible could someone explain how to make the following work?

As a work around I tried to use a base, non template class and inherit the template class from it.

```
 class templateInterface{
     virtual bool someFunction() = 0;
 };

 template <typename T>
 class templateClass : public templateInterface{
     bool someFunction();
 };
```

I then created a vector to store the base "templateInterface" class:

```
std::vector<templateInterface> v;
templateClass<int> t;
v.push_back(t);
```

This produced the following error:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'templateInterface'
note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'templateInterface'
note: virtual bool templateInterface::someFunction()
```

To fix this error I made the function in templateInterface not a pure virtual by providing a function body, this compiled but when calling the function the overide is not used, but instead the body in the virtual function.

Eg:

```
 class templateInterface{
     virtual bool someFunction() {return true;}
 };

 template <typename T>
 class templateClass : public templateInterface{
     bool someFunction() {return false;}
 };

 std::vector<templateInterface> v;
 templateClass<int> i;
 v.push_back(i);
 v[0].someFunction(); //This returns true, and does not use the code in the 'templateClass' function body
```

Is there any way to fix this so that the overridden function is used, or is there another workaround to store multiple template types in a single vector?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627215/how-to-make-a-vector-of-template-structs

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Why your code doesn't work:**

Calling a virtual function on a *value* doesn't use polymorphism. It calls the function which is defined for the type of this exact symbol as seen by the compiler, not the runtime type. When you insert sub types into a vector of the base type, your values will be *converted* into the base type ("type slicing"), which is not what you want. Calling functions on them will now call the function as defined for the base type, since not it *is* of that type.

**How to fix this?**

The same problem can be reproduced with this code snippet:

```
templateInterface x = templateClass<int>(); // Type slicing takes place!
x.someFunction();  // -> templateInterface::someFunction() is called!
```

Polymorphism only works on a *pointer* or *reference* type. It will then use the *runtime type* of the object behind the pointer / reference to decide which implementation to call (by using it's vtable).

Converting pointers is totally "safe" with regard to type slicing. Your *actual* values won't be converted at all and polymorphism will work as expected.

Example, analogous to the code snippet above:

```
templateInterface *x = new templateClass<int>();  // No type slicing takes place
x->someFunction();  // -> templateClass<int>::someFunction() is called!

delete x;  // Don't forget to destroy your objects.
```

**What about vectors?**

So you have to adopt these changes in your code. You can simply store *pointers* to actual types in the vector, instead of storing the values directly.

When working with pointers you also have to care about deleting your allocated objects. For this you can use *smart pointers* which care about deletion automatically. `unique_ptr` is one such smart pointer type. It deletes the pointee whenever it goes out of scope ("unique ownership" - the scope being the owner). Assuming the lifetime of your objects is bound to the scope this is what you should use:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<templateInterface>> v;

templateClass<int> *i = new templateClass<int>();    // create new object
v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<templateInterface>(i));  // put it in the vector

v.emplace_back(new templateClass<int>());   // "direct" alternative
```

Then, call a virtual function on one of these elements with the following syntax:

```
v[0]->someFunction();
```

Make sure you make all functions *virtual* which should be possible to be overridden by subclasses. Otherwise their overridden version will not be called. But since you already introduced an "interface", I'm sure you are working with abstract functions.

**Alternative approaches:**

Alternative ways to do what you want is to use a *variant* type in the vector. There are some implementations of variant types, the [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) being a very popular one. This approach is especially nice if you don't have a type hierarchy (for example when you store primitive types). You would then use a vector type like `std::vector<boost::variant<int, char, bool>>`

Comment: The smart pointer _may_ be the correct solution, but in his example code, he wasn't allocating the objects dynamically.  If they're objects with static lifetime, you don't want use a smart pointer on them, just take their address.  And if he does need a copy (because the initializing objects won't have sufficient lifetime), then you probably should say so.

Comment: `v.emplace_back(new templateClass<int>();`

Comment: @JamesKanze: in his origional code, the vector was containing copies of the locals.  Unless he specifies otherwise, I'd guess that the vector needs to keep containing copies, which requires dynamic allocation for polymorphism.

Comment: And calling a virtual function always resolves to the runtime type of the object.  The problem isn't the lack of dynamic dispatch; the problem is slicing.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, I edited my answer and tried to address these points too.

Comment: This solution works well :), thank you. The vector is actually in a class so I can easily delete the objects the pointers point at in the destructor to take care of deleting them at the end of their life.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of options to take care about memory management. Just make sure you delete it *somewhere*. Smart pointers are there to make the life of programmers easier, but you don't *have* to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism only works through pointers or references.  You'll
need the non-template base.  Beyond that, you'll need to decide
where the actual objects in container will live.  If they're all
static objects (with sufficient lifetime), just using
a `std::vector<TemplateInterface*>`, and inserting with
`v.push_back(&t1);`, etc., should do the trick.  Otherwise,
you'll probably want to support cloning, and keep clones in the
vector: preferably with Boost pointer containers, but
`std::shared_ptr` can be used as well.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions given so far are fine though be aware that in case you were returning the template type other than bool in your example , none of these would help as the vtable slots would not be able to be measured before hand. There are actually limits , from a design point of view , for using a template oriented polymorphic solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution nr. 1

This solution inspired by Sean Parent's C++ Seasoning talk. I highly recommend to check it out on youtube. My solution simplified a bit and the key is to store object in method itself.

#### One method only

Create a class that will invoke method of stored object.

```
struct object {
    template <class T>
    object(T t)
    : someFunction([t = std::move(t)]() { return t.someFunction(); })
    { }

    std::function<bool()> someFunction;
};
```

Then use it like this

```
std::vector<object> v;

// Add classes that has 'bool someFunction()' method
v.emplace_back(someClass());
v.emplace_back(someOtherClass());

// Test our vector
for (auto& x : v)
    std::cout << x.someFunction() << std::endl;
```

#### Several methods

For several methods use shared pointer to share object between methods

```
struct object {
    template <class T>
    object(T&& t) {
        auto ptr = std::make_shared<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
        someFunction = [ptr]() { return ptr->someFunction(); };
        someOtherFunction = [ptr](int x) { ptr->someOtherFunction(x); };
    }

    std::function<bool()> someFunction;
    std::function<void(int)> someOtherFunction;
};
```

#### Other types

Primitive types (such as `int`, `float`, `const char*`) or classes (`std::string` etc.) may be wrapped in the same way as `object` class do but behave differently. For example:

```
struct otherType {
    template <class T>
    otherType(T t)
    : someFunction([t = std::move(t)]() {
            // Return something different
            return true;
        })
    { }

    std::function<bool()> someFunction;
};
```

So now it is possible to add types that does not have `someFunction` method.

```
v.emplace_back(otherType(17));      // Adding an int
v.emplace_back(otherType("test"));  // A string
```

## Solution nr. 2

After some thoughts what we basically done in first solution is created array of callable functions. So why not just do the following instead.

```
// Example class with method we want to put in array
struct myclass {
    void draw() const {
        std::cout << "myclass" << std::endl;
    }
};

// All other type's behaviour
template <class T>
void draw(const T& x) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ": " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    myclass x;
    int y = 17;

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> v;

    v.emplace_back(std::bind(&myclass::draw, &x));
    v.emplace_back(std::bind(draw<int>, y));

    for (auto& fn : v)
        fn();
}
```

## Conclusion

Solution nr. 1 is definitely an interesting method that does not require inheritance nor virtual functions. And can be used to other stuff where you need to store a template argument to be used later.

Solution nr. 2, on the other hand, is simpler, more flexible and probably a better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at a container to store multiple types, then you should explore [boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) from the popular boost library.