# Vector of template class

Tags: c++, generics

(I've read several existing questions regarding this issue and they seem slightly different and don't make the issue any clearer to me.)

I'm trying to create a vector of key-value pairs in which the value is generic. The code which *logically indicates* what I need follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class CCmd
{
    protected:
        char name[64];
        T value;

    public:
        CCmd(char* _name, T _value)
        {
            strcpy(name, _name);
            value = _value;
        }

        T getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        void setValue(T _value)
        {
            value = _value;
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<CCmd*> vec;

    vec.push_back(new CCmd<int>("gravity", 150));
    vec.push_back(new CCmd<char*>("configfile", "config.cfg"));

    printf("Value = %d\n", vec[0]->getValue());
    printf("Config = %s\n", vec[1]->getValue());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This fails to compile in every way I think it would be syntactically correct. I read on one question that using a base class to encapsulate the generic class is required, however I tried this by creating an empty class as indicated and made my generic class a subclass of it:

```
...
class CCmdBase
{
};

class CCmd : public CCmdBase
{
...
```

and the compiler complains that `CCmdBase` doesn't have a member named `getValue` which, given that it returns the generic type T, would mean that the base class would also need to be generic for me to define it in there, which means that I'm back where I'm started?

Please help; what am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing much. I'd drop the getter and setter entirely and use the visitor pattern for inspection instead.

Comment: Since CCmd is a template class - isn't this wrong: "std::vector<CCmd*>"?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, I wrote code that "logically indicated" what I needed.

Comment: You can have a look at the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527673/c-one-stdvector-containing-template-class-of-multiple-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach cannot be easily done in C++. Most probably your design is incorrect and should be improved. It is difficult to advise exact way, but possible solution to have abstract base class with pure virtual functions. Though your virtual function cannot be `setValue` or `getValue` in your current "design" as function signature must match for virtual functions.

In case you really need to implement approach with different values in the vector look into `std::tuple`, `boost::variant` and `boost::any`. Again do not expect that usage of such solution will be easy to understand and straightforward for you.

Comment: TBQH, I feel that this is one of those rare occasions where the OP's design is not inherently flawed, but is being limited by a peculiarity of sorts within C++. Please understand: I do not say this lightly, and I do not say this often! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect: `std::vector<CCmd*> vec;`

You must specify a type for the template parameter. `CCmd` isn't a type, it's the name of a class template. For example , `std::vector< CCmd<int> *> vec;`

It's not possible to have a vector which directly stores items of different types.  The vector must store items of the same type.  The thing you are looking for is called a *heterogenous container*. Standard C++ doesn't have any, but you can simulate one by using a common type which has functions to retrieve the "real" object.

Your idea of `std::vector<CCmdBase *>` will work, using runtime polymorphism. Of course you have to actually implement the functions you want in the `CCmdBase` class. You can have template functions inside a non-template class definition, e.g.:

```
struct CCmdBase
{
    template<typename T> T getValue()
    {
         return dynamic_cast< CCmd<T> & >(*this).getValue();
    }

    virtual ~CCmdBase() {}
 };
```

Comment: As you anyway have to explicitly specify the type when you invoke `getValue()` from the base class, you could also use a static cast: `static_cast<CCmd<T> const&>(*this).getValue()`.

Comment: @davidhigh OK, although that causes UB if you specify the type wrong. Mine will throw an exception in that case.

Comment: This is why I suggested the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As this question was recently tagged as the 'duplicate' of a new question, is should be added that since C++17 we have [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

> The class `std::any` describes a type-safe container for single values of any type.

and [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

> The class template `std::variant` represents a type-safe union. An instance of `std::variant` at any given time either holds a value of one of its alternative types, or in the case of error - no value.

as part of the C++ standard.